# How can $\{1,2\}$ and $\{n \in \mathbb{N}: \text{there exists} \ x,y,z \in \mathbb{N^{+}}\text{such that}\ x^{n}+y^{n}=z^{n}\}$ be equal?

Tags: number-theory

On my textbook, it says that $X_{1}=\{1,2\}$ and

$$X_{2}=\lbrace n \in \mathbb{N}: \text{there exists} \  x,y,z \in \mathbb{N^{+}}\text{such that}\ x^{n}+y^{n}=z^{n}\rbrace,$$

and $X_{1}=X_{2}.$

It also pointed out that this is true is because of Andrew Wiles's proof of Fermat's last theorem.

I don't know anything about Fermat's last theorem, would you give me some hints how to relate to this?

Comment: Have you looked up Fermat's Last Theorem on Wikipedia?

Comment: This is really easy to prove.  I don't have room for it in the comment box sadly.

Comment: You should be readily able to prove that $X_1\subseteq X_2$. With lots of work, you possibly find e.g. that $3\notin X_2$. But the full proof of $X_1=X_2$ took the math world centuries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fermat's Last Theorem states that (where $n$ is a natural number):

$$\text{no three positive integers} \quad x,y,z\in\mathbb{N}\quad\text{satisfy the equation}\quad x^n+y^n=z^n \quad\text{for}\quad n>2$$

Therefore since

$$X_{2}=\lbrace n \in \mathbb{N}: \text{there exists} \  x,y,z \in \mathbb{N^{+}}\text{such that}\ x^{n}+y^{n}=z^{n}\rbrace,$$

we then have $X_2\subseteq X_1 $.

Note that $3^2+4^2=5^2$ and $3^1+2^1=5^1$. Therefore $X_1\subseteq X_2$. Thus $X_1=X_2$.

Comment: Technically, "therefore $X_2 \subseteq X_1$" :)

Comment: Oh, since OP used both $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb N^+$ notations, I guess OP has to prove that $0\not\in X_2$ either.

Comment: @pjs36: No, technically, this only proves that $X_2\subseteq\{0,1,2\}$. Of course it's easy to show that $0\notin X_2$, but it doesn't follow from Fermat's Last Theorem. Note that the explicit usage of $\mathbb N^+$ shows that the definition of $\mathbb N$ that includes $0$ is used.

Comment: OK, I think together we've taken care of *most* of the details, nice work, all.

Comment: @Celtschk it depends on what textbooks, some textbook take $\mathbb{N^{+}}$ as natural number starting from 1, some otherwise.

Comment: @Tmm: I don't think there's a textbook that uses **both** $\mathbb N$ **and** $\mathbb N^+$, but doesn't use them in the way that $0\in\mathbb N$ and $0\notin\mathbb N^+$.